# Why is SE engine removing spaces before question marks in titles? Please make it stop

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

I write my question titles with a space before the question mark, as recommended by standard French typography. I even spend time editing other people’s posts to add these spaces when missing, including in titles. And now, I realize that these are ignored and automatically removed by the SE engine.

Please make it stop!

Comment: Ouch, I see it happens even with unbreakable spaces! C'mon @StackExchange, if I take the trouble to put an unbreakable space, don't you think I mean it‽

Comment: Try an unremovable space.

Comment: @Joubarc what do you call an unremovable space? It also happens with *unbreakable* spaces, as Gilles mention. I only ever put unbreakable spaces before punctuation, anyway :)

Comment: I nearly added "just kidding" but didn't want to infer people wouldn't get it :-) My mistake. Also: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DontExplainTheJoke

Comment: Filed a [bug report/feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103855/please-preserve-spaces-before-punctuation-in-title-at-least-unbreakable-ones) to the main Meta. Please upvote it there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-breaking spaces and punctuation on Stack Exchange](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/non-breaking-spaces-and-punctuation-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there was a such a rule. Personally, and honestly, I don't like when people put that space, but I guess it only (now) applies to the other languages... I didn't know in French it was the rule. :)

Comment: @Alenanno not to worry, even some French native speakers don't know it either. Errrmmmmm...

Comment: You shouldn't be changing people's posts to add those spaces in, while that may be correct in European French, the rule does not exist for those of us in Canada. (At least, as far as I know. I am not a native Québécois Francophone but I have never seen the space before question mark being done here.)

Comment: @Shva That's correct, it is recommended in Canada to actually *not* put a space before any punctuation mark aside the colon and quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

[This automatic rewriting has been disabled on French Language & Usage.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103855/please-preserve-spaces-before-punctuation-in-title-at-least-unbreakable-ones/114478#114478)

Cette réécriture automatique a été désactivée sur notre site.

Comment: +1 for teaching me the word "échappatoire".